# Python will not run in windows powershell

Tags: python, powershell, python-2.7

I am trying to get python.exe to run in interactive mode in windows powershell. I have added c:\python27 to my PATH and when I type "python" in into the shell a new command prompt window opens running python, rather than running within powershell. This is a problem as when I run things like "python --version" it launches the new command prompt window and then closes before I can read it. Does anyone know how to get python to run in powershell?

Note: this used to work before I started to install pip, easy_install and virtualenv this morning.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just solved this issue after nearly pulling my hair out. Thought I would share. In windows system > advanced system settings > environment variables there are two places to change the PATH, user variables and system variables. I added ";c:\python27" as the value for PATH in both. It now works

Comment: before I only had ;c:\python27 in user and not system variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in PS, but when I need to use python in interactive mode in windows powershell, I use something like this (version of python is 2.7.3, I didn't change env variables):

PS C:\Python27> ./python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: I just solved this issue after nearly pulling my hair out. Thought I would share. In windows system > advanced system settings > environment variables there are two places to change the PATH, user variables and system variables. I added ";c:\python27" as the value for PATH in both. It now works.